# If A, B, C, D are non-invertible $n \times n$ matrices, is it true that their $2n \times 2n$ block matrix is non-invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
A & B \\
C & D \\\end{array} \right)$

is non-invertible?

Assume that the matrix is over a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the $2\times 2$ matrices that make up $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
(This example works   over all fields, no matter what characteristic).

Answer (score 3):

No. I think the simplest counterexample is the permutation matrix
$$
P=\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
\hline
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right].
$$
**Edit:** In general, for every $n\ge2$, the $2n\times2n$ permutation matrix containing ones at positions $(k,2k-1)$ and $(n+k,2k)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$ will serve as a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Assume $A$ has half $1$ on the upper diagonal and $B$ have half 1 on the lower diagonal, $C$ has half $1$ on the lower diagonal and $D$ has half $1$ on the upper diagonal. Then $A,B,C,D$ are all singular, but after some shifting the matrix become $I$.