# The rank of a square 2 by 2 block matrix with singular square blocks

Tags: linear-algebra

I have tried to prove or disprove the following statement using Penrose-Moore pseudoinverses, but all of the literature on that subject seems to focus on the case $m \not= n$, i.e. rectangular matrices, rather than singular square matrices.

> Let $M = \begin{bmatrix} M_1 & M_2 \\ M_3 & M_4 \end{bmatrix}$, where $M$ is a $2m \times 2m$ matrix, and $M_1 , M_2, M_3, M_4$ are $m \times m$ square matrices, all with determinant zero. Moreover, **no two adjacent blocks** of the $M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4$ are symmetric (hence the answers given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532328/if-a-b-c-d-are-non-invertible-n-times-n-matrices-is-it-true-that-their-2) are non-examples, because all of the blocks are symmetric).
>
> Show that $M$ has determinant zero, or find a counterexample where $M$ is not singular.

Any help or insights with this problem would be greatly appreciated; I know this is probably a simple problem, but I am not sure how to apply the Laplace expansion in the case that the block matrices just have determinant zero, rather than being all zeros.

This answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1347444/327486) says that the answer is affirmative and trivial, but I am not seeing it unfortunately.

The condition regarding symmetry may seem random, but it is motivated by the fact that in such cases we can replace the blocks by their characteristic polynomial and still achieve desirable results. See, for example, here: http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/new/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf

Comment: I edited the question so that it is not a duplicate. The answers given to the other question do not answer the question in the case of the added condition that none of the block matrices are symmetric, since both answers given had at least one symmetric block.

Comment: The accepted answer on that post has exactly one symmetric block, so it satisfies your condition

Comment: In any case, the counterexample
$$
P=\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]
$$
has no symmetric blocks

Comment: @Omnomnomnom OK thank you so much! It looks like it is probably symplectic too, which is why I am asking this question, so it does seem like no simple proof (using the determinants of the blocks) that all symplectic matrices have unit determinant is possible.

Comment: if you're looking to prove that fact about symplectic matrices, why not post a question about that?

Comment: well it's not true for symplectic matrices, as your example shows